# Magento 2: How to load another customer data on checkout instead of current logged in customer via custom module?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, session, customer-address

I want to show a customers list as dropdown on checkout page and when I change the customer from that dropdown list, All details like shipping addresses, customer detail should be change according to that selected customer. But the current loggedin customer should not logout and order should be place for selected customer from that dropdown list.

Best solutions are warmly welcome please!

Comment: You can try to add a ui component in checkout page with list of customers you want. Then you need to customise each and every process of checkout

Comment: Can you share any article by which I can follow to add a ui component ?

Comment: This is not good practice to change every data in checkout, Instead of that you create order programmatically as you want.

Comment: Yes, but I need to make 3 type of orders and my client's requirement is to use only once checkout page process for all three kind of orders. Thats why I require to add a customers dropdown on checkout page. I will select a customer, then all the information billing shipping will be change according to that customer & I can place order for that customer from checkout page